# How to use methods in a informal protocol in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, protocols

I am learning to program a simple Web Browser Mac App in Objective C. I have a simple textfield as an address bar and a Webview. As such, I wish to update the address the website in the textfield whenever the page changes when I click a link.

After googling, I realise I could use a method

```
    didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame
```

in the WebFrameLoadDelegate Protocol. I then proceed to type

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate,WebFrameLoadDelegate>
```

which resulted in an error. After further search I found out that is due to WebFrameLoadDelegate being an informal Protocol.

My question is then this: What is the syntax for using the method below specified by the informal Protocol?

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame*)frame;
```

Comment: For an informal protocol you don't need to do anything other than implement the delegate methods (and set your delegate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're manually creating a webview, then just set your own class as the delegate as following `[webview setDelegate:self]`.  But if you made the webview in IB instead, you can link the delegate there instead.

[image]

Once you set your class as the delegate of the webview, you can just implement that method without any extra code.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame*)frame
{
    //Do stuff here.
}
```

And the WebView will simply call your method whenever it finishes loading a frame.

If you want to know how this works, it all goes back to the construction of a delegate.  WebView will check if delegate is nil or not.  If it's not, then it will call `respondsToSelector:` to check if the delegate has implemented the delegate method.  An informal delegate is just an old way of allowing optional protocol method, which shouldn't be used anymore as stated by @JonathanGrynspan

And if you didn't know, you don't have to explicitly declare that your class confirms to a protocol (even if it's not informal) if you connect it in IB.

By the way, if you're working on a webview, check out Apple's [development guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000164i) on it.  It gives you a step-by-step tutorial on creating the basics of a webview including when to change the webview's URL address.

Comment: Well it didnt work when i dragged it to file's owner. however it did work when i drag it to app delegate.

Comment: Oops.  I thought you were using a document-based application/window controller.  If it's in the mainmenu.nib, drag it to the app delegate instead.

Answer (score 4):

With an informal protocol, you implement the methods without declaring conformation to a protocol. `WebFrameLoadDelegate` is not a type, just the name of an `NSObject`category.

They exist because, previously, there was no way to specify that a method in a protocol was optional (the `@optional` and `@required` keywords did not exist.) When the requisite keywords were added to Objective-C, Apple started moving to formal protocols with optional methods, which makes for better type safety and self-documenting code.